# Get the collection item with the minimum and maximum value for each distinct item name in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-collection

I'm working on a small app using Laravel 5.8 for a dog shelter.

I have a query in my Dog model which retrieves the dog breeds I'm interested in:

```
public function getBreeds()
    {
        return $collection = DB::table('dogs')->whereIn('name', ['Breed1', 'Breed2', 'Breed3', 'Breed4'])->get();
    }
```

I get a collection with around 100 items looking like this:

```
Collection {#373 ▼
  #items: array:100 [▼
    0 => {#380 ▼
      +"id": 1792
      +"join_date": "2019-03-21 07:40"
      +"name": "Breed1"
      +"age": 9.3
    }
    1 => {#382 ▼
      +"id": 1801
      +"join_date": "2019-03-21 09:35"
      +"name": "Breed2"
      +"age": 29.1
    }
    2 => {#372 ▼
      +"id": 1803
      +"join_date": "2019-03-21 14:10"
      +"name": "Breed3"
      +"age": 60.9
    }
    3 => {#385 ▼
      +"id": 1805
      +"join_date": "2019-03-21 14:12"
      +"name": "Breed4"
      +"age": 0.7
    }
    4 => {#386 ▼
      +"id": 1806
      +"join_date": "2019-03-21 14:14"
      +"name": "Breed1"
      +"age": 75.4
    }
    5 => {#387 ▼
      +"id": 2872
      +"join_date": "2019-03-21 16:07"
      +"name": "Breed2"
      +"age": 9.5
    }
    6 => {+"name": "Breed3"}
    7 => {+"name": "Breed4"}
    8 => {+"name": "Breed1"}
    9 => {+"name": "Breed2"}
    10 => {+"name": "Breed3"}
    100 => {}
  ]
}
```

I need to get the **two collection items** *for each* breed where the age is the lowest and the highest. This should result in a collection of eight items with 4 distinct breeds (as queried) with the youngest and the oldest dog from each breed.

I've tried using `filter()` or `each()` in combination with `min()` and `max()`, but I can't get the desired output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First group the `$collection` by name.
Then for each `group` find the `max` and `min` object.

**Example Code**

```php
$collection->groupBy('name')->map(function($group, $groupName) {
    return [
        'name' => $groupName,
        'dogs' => [
            'min' => $group->firstWhere('age', $group->min('age')),
            'max' => $group->firstWhere('age', $group->max('age')),
        ]; 
    ];
});
```